# Angular Datepicker displaying twice in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm new to Angular JS. I was working with Angular JS calendar and am trying to display the angular Datepicker inside Bootstrap modal window. However the Datepicker is displayed twice as shown in the image below.

Here's my modal html code.

```
<div class="modal-header">
<h3 class="modal-title">{{ vm.event.event.title }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="event in vm.event track by $index">
<h3 class="post-subtitle">
  {{event.type}}
</h3>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <th>Starts on</th>
  <th>Ends on</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <td>
    <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
      <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          readonly
          uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
          ng-model="event.startsAt"
          is-open="event.startOpen"
          close-text="Close" >                  
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-default"
          ng-click="vm.object.toggle($event, 'startOpen', event)">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </p>
    <uib-timepicker
      ng-model="event.startsAt"
      hour-step="1"
      minute-step="15"
      show-meridian="true">
    </uib-timepicker>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        readonly
        uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
        ng-model="event.endsAt"
        is-open="event.endOpen"
        close-text="Close">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-default"
          ng-click="vm.object.toggle($event, 'endOpen', event)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </p>
    <uib-timepicker
      ng-model="event.endsAt"
      hour-step="1"
      minute-step="15"
      show-meridian="true">
    </uib-timepicker>
  </td>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">OK</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to have both `uib-timepicker-popup` attribute and the `uib-timepicker` tag?

Comment: I can remove the `uib-timepicker` tag. But that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What you want to achieve? Remove one datepicker from modal?

Comment: The datepicker is appearing in the background div also as seen in the image. I want to remove that